# How many bijective functions can be?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Be $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. how many bijective functions can it be, if $f(\{1,2,3 \}\subseteq\{ 3,4,5,6,7\}$?

Comment: Hint: The image of $1$ can be selected in $5$ ways. For each of these ways, the image of $2$ can be selected in $4$ ways. For $\dots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is the number of permutations where the first three numbers are not $1$ or $2$

First select $f(1),f(2),f(3)$. Which is selecting the first three digits. Now note that any permutation of the remaining elements gives a different permutation. There are $(5\cdot4\cdot3)$ ways to do this. Now select an appropriate permutation of the remaining $4$ elements in $4!$ ways to get the solution is $5!\cdot12$